# dynamic_cast inside dervied constructor

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have a base class and derived class and also a BaseType and DerivedType. on the Base class i Have an object (not a pointer) of BaseType.
I want on Derived class's constructor to do a dynamic cast from BaseType to DerivedType.

```
class DerivedType: public BaseType{};

class Base{
    BaseType basetype; //not a pointer
}

class Derived : public Base{
    Derived(){
        //I want to do in this constructor a dynamic_cast from
        // "basetype" to "DerivedType"
        // when "DerivedType" inherits from "BaseType" also
    }
};
```

I have both classes `class DerivedType: public BaseType` `class Derived : public Base`

On `Base` class I have an object of `BaseType` (not a pointer)

and I need on `Derived` class's constructor to change the type of this object to `DerivedType` my boss told me to use `dynamic_cast`

I need to do it because if i'll use `class C : public Derived`

When i'll use 'basetype' it will be automaticly `DerivedType` and not `BaseType`

Comment: I don't think I understand. Do you want `Base` to have a member of class `BaseType` and `Derived` to have a member of `DerivedType`? This is possible. Do you want `Derived`'s `DerivedType`-object to be the same object as the corresponding `Base`'s `BaseType`-object? That's not directly expressible. In any case; why do you think you need `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: What do you intend to cast with the dynamic cast? There are no instances of `DerivedType` pointed by a `BaseType*` anywhere in your example.

Comment: It seems like you might be misunderstanding what a `dynamic_cast` is for. Could you give more detail about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: if i understood your question: 1. I can add what I want on Derived class in order to cast the object of BaseType to DerivedType 2. I think I need dynamic_cast because this is what may boss told me to use

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I do it?
so when i'll call to `basetype` from `class C` I'll get `basetype` of type `DerivedType`

Answer (score 2):

You can't *change* the type of the member `basetype`, whether by using `dynamic_cast` or any other means.
If your boss told you to do it, they're either very wrong or didn't communicate clearly enough what you should do.  I would recommend that you ask for clarification.

One common way to implement this (i.e. a member whose type depends on a subclass) is by turning the base class into a template, passing the member's type as a parameter:

```
template<typename MemberType = BaseType>  // Default type is BaseType
class Base{
    MemberType something;
}

class Derived : public Base <DerivedType>
{
      Derived()
      {
          // 'something' has type DerivedType
      }
};
```

Comment: Your solution rather negates the point of deriving from `Base`, doesn't it.  Because there is no longer a common base class, and polymorphism won't work.

Answer (score 0):

One very important point: once an object is constructed, its type is
fixed, and can never be changed, regardless.  If `Base` has a member
named `basetype`, that object is constructed by the constructor of
`Base`, before any derived class can access it, and the type of that
object is what is declared to be in `Base`, and can never be changed.
You *can* use `dynamic_cast` on it (e.g. `dynamic_cast<DerivedType&>`),
but that cast is guaranteed to fail.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  Perhaps some variant of
the strategy pattern is what you're looking for, where `Base::basetype`
is a pointer or a reference to an object passed into `Base::Base()` by
`Derived::Derived()`.  Or perhaps it's really the value of `basetype`
which should change, which is no problem.  (This is what the name
suggests.)  Describe what you are trying to achieve, and we can perhaps
find a solution.